# Некорректно отображается datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Добрый день, вот такого рода проблема : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии  на input вызывается календарь, но он никак не реагирует на нажатия по датам.  Input подгружается через ajax. В head подключил:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Datepicker вызываю

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '#datepicker',  function() {
$( '#datepicker' ).datepicker();
 } );
</script>
```

в консоли ошибок нет, подскажите,пожалуйста, как можно побороть данную проблему?

Comment: `https` забыли в ссылке на css файл.

Comment: @Suvitruf, хром игнорирует отсутствие+ в консоли чисто по этому поводу, но с https всё равно проблема та же

Comment: А в dev консоли что? Все эти скрипты/стили точно загрузились?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема скорее-всего в `z-index`. Ваш календарь лежит "под" вашими кнопками(или под контейнером с кнопками). Вы переопределяли им `z-index`? Если да - то либо дайте вашему `datepicker` этот аттрибут больше, чем у кнопок.

Comment: Да,спасибо, добавил к классу z-index и всё встало на свои места!

Answer (score 0):

Вы странно подключаете Datepicker.
Он должен срабатывать при загрузке окна, а не после клика.
Примерно так:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();      
});
</script>
```

Comment: datapicker загружается позже загрузки страницы - через ajax, в таком случае он же работать не будет тк DOM дерево было построено до того как загружен скрипт.Поправьте,если не прав.

Comment: Согласен. При Ajax загрузке как я написал не сработает. Тогда скорее нужно навешивать Datepicker где-нибудь в callback аякса. А у вас получается что при каждом клике каждый раз навешивается новый Datepicker. (Могу ошибаться)

Comment: не не при каждом, а по конкретному элементу с id =datepicker:)